# knexjs column specific type

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

How can I specific type of column in knexJS?

I have the table ***Users***:

```
id serial NOT NULL,
id_file_avatar bigint,
id_sectors bigint NOT NULL,
name character varying(50),
email character varying(100)
```

When I get in my rest I got it:

```
{  
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "id_file_avatar": null,
    "id_sectors": "0",
    "name": "Rodrigo Lopes",
    "email": "rodlps22@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

My ***UserModel***

```
var User = bookshelf
    .Model
    .extend({
        tableName: 'users',
        visible: [
            'id',
            'id_file_avatar',
            'id_sectors',
            'name',
            'email'
        ],
        soft: false,

        initialize: function () {
            //this.on('saving', this.validateSave);
        },

        validateSave: function () {
            return new Checkit(rules).run(this.attributes);
        }
    });
```

But the ***id_sectors*** should be a ***int type***, anyone knows why?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you actually *save* `id_sectors` as integer?

From the documentation:

> For example `new Model({id: '1'}).load([relations...])` will not return the same as `Model({id: 1}).load([relations...])` - notice that the id is a string in one case and a number in the other. This can be a common mistake if retrieving the id from a url parameter.

Try using validator for your model, and set that `id_sectors` must be integer: https://github.com/fluxxu/bookshelf-validator

Additionally, should this not work, you can always use `parseInt` to change your string value to integer.

As for defining a model with attribute types, I don't think that's (currently) possible.

Comment: Sorry my bad, It was String, But I had problem with relationship, I read it and resolve (https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry) thanks man =)